# how to find lowest 2 or more values

Tags: spreadsheet

I have rows of data and would like to sum all but the lowest 2 or 3 or 4 entries.
What is the easiest way to do this?  Does it involve a macro.

I prefer open office spreadsheet, but could also use excel if the answer for excel is much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the **SMALL function** in excel it will definitely get you the second, third or the fourth lowest value in that row

Resource taken from  [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52363&page=1)

---

**Instructions on using SMALL function** ([taken from here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2221964_use-excels-small-function.html))

> - Start Microsoft Excel. Open an existing spreadsheet that contains a
>     range of numbers in which you would
>     like to find the smallest.
> - Click on the cell in the Excel spreadsheet where you want to enter
>     the SMALL function into. This is where
>     the result of the cell will show up
>     when it is calculated.
> - Determine what range you want to use to find the smallest number. Use cell
>     references to refer to the cell range.
>     For example, if you have values in
>     cells B1 through B5, your cell range
>     would be B1:B5.
> - Type the SMALL function into the cell. The SMALL function syntax is
>     "=Small(array, nth_position)." Array
>     is the cell range or array and
>     nth_position is the position starting
>     at the smallest that you want to
>     return. For the example above, you
>     would use the function of
>     "=SMALL(B1:B5), 1" (without the
>     quotation marks) to find the smallest
>     number in the range of B1:B5.
> - Press the "Enter" key to enter the function into Excel. You will now get
>     a return of the smallest number in the
>     specified range.
> - Use the SMALL function to create other formulas that return other
>     values. If you wanted to find the
>     second smallest number in our example
>     you would use the formula of
>     "=SMALL(B1:B5), 2" (without the
>     quotation marks).
> - Continue increasing the number at the end of the SMALL function to get
>     returns that go from the smallest to
>     the largest number.

Comment: NP.  thorough answer!

Comment: thank you.  this looks like I can use this to accomplish what I wanted.  I hope there is also a SMALL function that works the same way in OOo.

Comment: I just checked - it does work exactly this way in openoffice spreadsheet.  And here I thought I was going to have to learn how to write a macro to do this.

Comment: Actually, in openoffice there is a slight difference: the syntax is "=SMALL(B1:B5;2)" to get the second lowest value.

Comment: Dont forget to accept if this answered you , many new comers forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I've scrolled up and down and don't see a way to accept an answer.  I can only keep adding comments.

Comment: There should be  a TICK mark out there on the left side of the answer somewhat near the upvotes. You might need to login to super user first

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question more? Do you mean you want to add all values of a row but last 3 or 4? Generally you select the elements and add like sum(A1:X1), exluding the elements in Y1 and Z1 for row 1.

Comment: There's not much of a difference between open office spreadsheet and excel.

Comment: To Clarify, I don't mean to add all but the last 3 or 4.  I mean to add all but the smallest 3 or 4.   For example, if my data row is 3 4 3 5 4 6 7 5 4 5  the sum of all but the smallest 4 is 32 because the two 3's and two of the 4's are not included in the sum.